# mongoose .find() scope: How can I call found data out of the query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to call the the founded variable outside of the array but it return an empty array instead. Can someone explain why the console.log inside the function work but not outside of the function.

```
// Video Schema
let mongoose =  require("mongoose");

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var videoSchema = new Schema ({
  title: String,
  videoURL:  String,
  author: String,
  time: String,
  viewcount: Number,
  categories: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category"
  }],
    description: String,
})

let Video = mongoose.model("Video", videoSchema);

module.exports = {
  videoSchema: videoSchema,
  Video: Video
}
```

app.js

```
let Video = require(__dirname + "/dbs/Video.js").Video;

 app.get("/", function(req,res) {
    
    let videos = []
    Video.find(function(err, foundVideo) {
      if (!err) {
        videos = foundVideo.slice(0)
        console.log(videos) // this return me with an object array [{obj1}, {obj2}]
      } else {
        return err
      }
    })
    console.log(videos) // This return an empty array []

}
```

How can I store the foundVideos array in the videos variable so that can call the variable global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this operation:

```
Video.find(function(err, data) {
  // something
  console.log("one")
})
// nothing
console.log("two")
```

The function between parentheses is the callback of the `find()` operation. This means it will be called back when the find execution ends, and it may make use of `err` or `data` parameters inside its scope. It will execute the `console.log("one")`.
This way to "wait" for results is due to the asynchronous nature of js.

Instead, the code outside the callback method will be triggered just after the find is **called**, and it will not wait for the find operation to be **finished**. Therefore, in this example, `two` will be printed before `one`.

In your example, the variable `videos` you try to print outside the callback method `console.log(videos)` is empty as is printed before the `videos` are actually there.

You should write all your callback code in the `!err` case:

```
if (!err) {
  videos = foundVideo.slice(0)
  console.log(videos) // this return me with an object array [{obj1}, {obj2}]
}
```

**Update**

As you noticed, a coder is forced to implement the code in the callback method. Then, other methods or requests depending on the data from first request tend to make it complex to structure the code.

```
const processVideos = function(data) {
  if(!data) {
    // do something when data is empty
  }

  // process videos here
}

const notifyError = function(err) {
  if(!err)
     return

  // do something with the error here
}

Video.find(function(err, data) {
  processVideos(data)
  notifyError(err)
})
```

Use always your "genius" and programming patterns to avoid complex code, large methods and unreadable sections.

Comment: do you know any way to shorten this code? I have like 3 collections to query and render to an ejs template. This will make the code so ugly and hard to understand

Comment: yeap. You can avoid to do horrible code by using structured programming. I'll provide you an example in the answer.